# SharePoint 2013 SiteCollection creation error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, content-database, ups

I tried to create a new site collection for my web application and came through this error.
We recently created a new content database, does it has to do something with that? Do I have to make any changes to my web application to use the new content database.
And my UPS service also has some issues, the FIM service is not starting.

> Sorry, something went wrong  Could not allocate space for object in
>   database 'WSS claimtestapp' because the 'PRIMARY'  filegroup is full.
>   Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the
>   filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or  setting
>   autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.  fECHNlCAL DETAILS 
>   GO BACK TO SITE

[image]

Comment: Which SQL version you are using? Also check the SQL server hard disk space.

Comment: @AmalHashim SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like issue with Drive space on the DB Server. Make Sure

- Drive where you storing the MDF & LDF files should have of plenty of free space.
- Also make sure tempDB is not full.

You can run XP_Fixeddrives in SQL Management studio against the DB server, it will tell you how much free space on each drive.

Comment: Ive checked it, there is enough free space